# Select the whole table and convert a column

Tags: sql

I would like to `select * from myTable`, but because one of the columns data type is not supported, I would like to convert that to varchar(10).

How is this possible?

Comment: Which sql, what is the table structure, which column, what have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried Googling "sql convert to varchar"?

Comment: CAST(thatcolumn AS VARCHAR(10))

Comment: Also, you'll have to list every column now; select c1, c2, c3, ..., CAST..., cn from myTable.

Comment: SELECT cast(thatColumn as varchar(10))
FROM myTable  is working, but it I want to select my whole table, while converting this single column to varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can use CAST and CONVERT to change the returned value of a column in select statement but it is done by using column name in the select and not using `select * from table`.
See the following link for detailed explanations of these functions:
[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Here is an example of using CAST:

```
SELECT a,b,c,CAST(d AS float) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: The only problem is, that my table has more, than 1000 columns. Is there no way to do this with using select * ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something like

```
select *,convert (varchar(10), column) from table
```

Comment: Your answer would be only okay (especially after Tunaki's formatting), if you explained, what your code is doing and how. The reason behind that, that a code snippet copy-paste site would have a much lower quality as if we can consult and think together in eachothers problem.